# JSF Load uploaded images from nested subfolders

Tags: image, jsf

In my web application, I want to upload images and hence present them using p:graphicImage.  I store the uploaded images outside the web app – in particular at E:\webapp\upload.  Note that my tomcat server is installed on E: volume.  I have created an ImageServlet to read the images as described in http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html.

I added the following configuration to my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>utilities.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I can access the images from the index.xhtml page using “upload/imageName.ext” eg:

```
<p:graphicImage value="upload/flag.gif" />
```

This jsf code is correctly converted into the following HTML code:

```
<img src=”http://localhost:8080/MyApp/upload/flag.gif?pfdrid_c=true”>
```

However, I want to be able to access images from pages which are contained into subfolders.  Eg I have one page which is located at “admin” subfolder:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/admin/language.xhtml
```

Inside that page, the same jsf code is converted into:

```
<img src=”http://localhost:8080/MyApp/admin/upload/flag.gif?pfdrid_c=true”>
```

which is wrong.

In other words, it looks for the images at “E:\webapp\admin\upload” directory which does not exist and hence nothing is displayed.  I can clearly write the following code:

```
<p:graphicImage value="../upload/flag.gif" />
```

to make it work but I consider this as a bad practice because I will have to adopt the path each time I am in a different subfolder hierarchy (consider for example the problem of nested subfolders).

I am wondering if there is any way to just specify the relative path of the image eg “upload/flag.gif” regardless of subfolder hierarchy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the path start with `/` to make it relative to the context root instead of the currently opened folder.

```
<p:graphicImage value="/upload/flag.gif" />
```